# LINQ exception on INSERT

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've code like that:

```
class Importer {
private DBContext m_context;
public Importer() {
    m_context = new DBContext();
}

public bool ImportPersons(List<MyPerson> p_Persons) {
    foreach (MyPerson p in p_Persons) {
        if (!import(p)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private bool import(MyPerson p_Person) {
    address = new adr();
    adr.city = p_Person.City;
    adr.country = p_Person.Country;
    adr.postal_code = p_Person.PostalCode;

    try {
        m_context.adresses.InsertOsSubmit(adr);
        m_context.SubmitChanges();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Addr import error: {0}", e.Message);
        return false;
    }

    person p = new person();
    p.id_address = adr.id_addres;
    p.name = p_Person.Name;
    p.sname = p_Person.SName;
    p.sex = p_Person.Sex;

    try {
        m_context.persons.InsertOnSubmit(p);
        m_context.SubmitChanges();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Person import error: {0}", e.Message);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

When I call ImportPersons method with list of 20 persons I receive sicne 6'th (to the end) exception: 
*Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use*
during inserting person object.

Alson when I start from 6'th the exception is occurs from the insert begin.

I have to add that address.id_address is autoincremet column in database.

Can you help me?

Comment: What are the constraints in the person table?

Comment: What is the `InsertOsSubmit` method doing?

Comment: Min - Max: addres 1 - M person, person 1 -1 address.

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating new entities with LINQ-to-SQL, never update the ID values directly.  This code assumes that your database has a foreign key relationship between the Person and Address tables:

```
private bool import(MyPerson p_person)
{
    address adr = new adr();
    adr.city = p_Person.City;
    adr.country = p_Person.Country;
    adr.postal_code = p_Person.PostalCode;

    person p = new person();
    p.adr = adr;
    p.name = p_Person.Name;
    p.sname = p_Person.SName;
    p.sex = p_Person.Sex;

    try {
        db.persons.InsertOnSubmit(p);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Person import error: {0}", e.Message);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is it really forbiden? Why first entities are adding correctly?

Comment: It isn't "forbidden"...it's just not necessary if your model is set up correctly. As far as your initial entities, I don't know the current state of your database and what records already exist. It could be that the ID's that are trying to be assigned already exist, which would be the reason for the exception.

Comment: Actually, it is quite strange that 5 records were imported successfully and the others are failed...

Comment: Is your target database completely empty when you run the import? If you have been testing and failures have occurred, you may already have address records in the database.  Do you have primary keys set for BOTH tables? In addition, I just noticed you are running two separate data contexts (mContext and db). That could definitely contribute to your problems. Operations such as these need to use the same data context.

Comment: Actually I've made typo - of course I always use the same member context - m_context. Are you able to talk using skype? Maybe if I could show you full code you would be able to help me. My skype contact is: Nick: spoon_r, Country: Poland

Comment: Are you able to talk using skype? Maybe if I could show you full code you would be able to help me. My skype contact is: Nick: spoon_r, Country: Poland. Please post me on skype if you whant. Thanks in advance!